# SQLiteQueryBuilder; cursor.getString() strips accents for characters

Tags: java, android-sqlite

Problem with cursor.getString(). It strips the single quote and accented characters of their accent.
Example: Mary Anning’s Plesiosaur -> Mary Annings Plesiosaur
Ki Te Ao Mārama -> Ki Te Ao Marama
The strings are valid in the SQLite DB and iOS app I have reads them correctly.
Is this a limitation of java String or SQLiteQueryBuilder/Cursor?
Is there a way around it or will I have to go lower level?
getBlob() returns ascii codes.

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

qb.setTables("art");
cursor = qb.query(artDB, new String[] {"name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor == null) { closeDatabase(); return names;}
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String s;
    do {
        s = cursor.getString(0);
        byte[] b = cursor.getBlob(0);
        String r = new String(b, StandardCharsets.);
        names.add(s);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a limitation of java String or SQLiteQueryBuilder/Cursor?

No, (as below)

> Is there a way around it or will I have to go lower level?

The device's locale or how the data is inserted would appear to be the issue (see following demo).

Consider this variation on your code:-

```
void logValRetrieval() {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables(TABLE_TEST);
    Cursor csr = qb.query(this.getWritableDatabase(),new String[]{TEST_COL_V1,TEST_COL_V2,TEST_COL_V3,TEST_COL_V4,TEST_COL_V5,TEST_COL_V6},null,null,null,null,null);
    int row_counter = 0;
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        row_counter++;
        for (String c: csr.getColumnNames()) {

            int idx = csr.getColumnIndex(c);
            Log.d(
                    "ROW" + row_counter, "COLUMN IS " + c
                            + "STR=" + csr.getString(idx)
                            + "INT=" + csr.getInt(idx)
                            + "DBL=" + csr.getDouble(idx)
                            + "NUM=" +  csr.getString(idx)
                            + "BLB=" + csr.getBlob(idx)
                            + "OTH=" + csr.getString(idx)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And some invoking code:-

```
    db = DBHelper.getInstance(this);

    db.insert("The quick brown fox ....");
    db.insert("Mary Anning’s Plesiosaur");
    db.insert("~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-");
    db.logValRetrieval();
```

The result output to the log being

```
2023-02-24 16:48:03.852 D/ROW1: COLUMN IS v1STR=The quick brown fox ....INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=The quick brown fox ....BLB=[B@98fd0f5OTH=The quick brown fox ....
2023-02-24 16:48:03.852 D/ROW1: COLUMN IS v2STR=The quick brown fox ....INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=The quick brown fox ....BLB=[B@664ce8aOTH=The quick brown fox ....
2023-02-24 16:48:03.852 D/ROW1: COLUMN IS v3STR=The quick brown fox ....INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=The quick brown fox ....BLB=[B@8962cfbOTH=The quick brown fox ....
2023-02-24 16:48:03.852 D/ROW1: COLUMN IS v4STR=The quick brown fox ....INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=The quick brown fox ....BLB=[B@ec7d118OTH=The quick brown fox ....
2023-02-24 16:48:03.852 D/ROW1: COLUMN IS v5STR=The quick brown fox ....INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=The quick brown fox ....BLB=[B@d598771OTH=The quick brown fox ....
2023-02-24 16:48:03.853 D/ROW1: COLUMN IS v6STR=The quick brown fox ....INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=The quick brown fox ....BLB=[B@8c94956OTH=The quick brown fox ....
2023-02-24 16:48:03.853 D/ROW2: COLUMN IS v1STR=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurINT=0DBL=0.0NUM=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurBLB=[B@909dd7OTH=Mary Anning’s Plesiosaur
2023-02-24 16:48:03.853 D/ROW2: COLUMN IS v2STR=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurINT=0DBL=0.0NUM=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurBLB=[B@8f4e6c4OTH=Mary Anning’s Plesiosaur
2023-02-24 16:48:03.853 D/ROW2: COLUMN IS v3STR=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurINT=0DBL=0.0NUM=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurBLB=[B@e2e29adOTH=Mary Anning’s Plesiosaur
2023-02-24 16:48:03.853 D/ROW2: COLUMN IS v4STR=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurINT=0DBL=0.0NUM=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurBLB=[B@328a4e2OTH=Mary Anning’s Plesiosaur
2023-02-24 16:48:03.853 D/ROW2: COLUMN IS v5STR=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurINT=0DBL=0.0NUM=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurBLB=[B@3574073OTH=Mary Anning’s Plesiosaur
2023-02-24 16:48:03.854 D/ROW2: COLUMN IS v6STR=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurINT=0DBL=0.0NUM=Mary Anning’s PlesiosaurBLB=[B@dbbab30OTH=Mary Anning’s Plesiosaur
2023-02-24 16:48:03.854 D/ROW3: COLUMN IS v1STR=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-BLB=[B@e30b3a9OTH=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-
2023-02-24 16:48:03.854 D/ROW3: COLUMN IS v2STR=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-BLB=[B@f302d2eOTH=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-
2023-02-24 16:48:03.854 D/ROW3: COLUMN IS v3STR=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-BLB=[B@4db70cfOTH=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-
2023-02-24 16:48:03.855 D/ROW3: COLUMN IS v4STR=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-BLB=[B@ce84a5cOTH=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-
2023-02-24 16:48:03.855 D/ROW3: COLUMN IS v5STR=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-BLB=[B@4b7e165OTH=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-
2023-02-24 16:48:03.855 D/ROW3: COLUMN IS v6STR=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-INT=0DBL=0.0NUM=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-BLB=[B@215ee3aOTH=~!@#$%^&*()_+:'/?.>,<[]{}`=-
```

i.e. No losses. Perhaps use App Inspection to view what data is stored e.g. for the above:-

[image]

The full DBHelper code, in case you want to try it (if it works then the issue isn't the locale) :-

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final  String TABLE_TEST = "test";
    public static final String TEST_COL_V1 = "v1";
    public static final String TEST_COL_V2 = "v2";
    public static final String TEST_COL_V3 = "v3";
    public static final String TEST_COL_V4 = "v4";
    public static final String TEST_COL_V5 = "v5";
    public static final String TEST_COL_V6 = "v6";
    private static final String TEST_CRTSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOt EXISTS " + TABLE_TEST + "("
            + TEST_COL_V1 +" TEXT "
            + "," + TEST_COL_V2 + " INTEGER "
            + "," + TEST_COL_V3 + " REAL "
            + "," + TEST_COL_V4 + " NUMERIC"
            + "," + TEST_COL_V5 + " BLOB"
            + "," + TEST_COL_V6 + " ANOTHER"
            + ")";

    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    private static DBHelper instance;
    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TEST_CRTSQL);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    long insert(String val) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TEST_COL_V1,val);
        cv.put(TEST_COL_V2,val);
        cv.put(TEST_COL_V3,val);
        cv.put(TEST_COL_V4,val);
        cv.put(TEST_COL_V5,val);
        cv.put(TEST_COL_V6,val);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_TEST,null,cv);
    }

    void logValRetrieval() {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables(TABLE_TEST);
        Cursor csr = qb.query(this.getWritableDatabase(),new String[]{TEST_COL_V1,TEST_COL_V2,TEST_COL_V3,TEST_COL_V4,TEST_COL_V5,TEST_COL_V6},null,null,null,null,null);
        int row_counter = 0;
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            row_counter++;
            for (String c: csr.getColumnNames()) {

                int idx = csr.getColumnIndex(c);
                Log.d(
                        "ROW" + row_counter, "COLUMN IS " + c
                                + "STR=" + csr.getString(idx)
                                + "INT=" + csr.getInt(idx)
                                + "DBL=" + csr.getDouble(idx)
                                + "NUM=" +  csr.getString(idx)
                                + "BLB=" + csr.getBlob(idx)
                                + "OTH=" + csr.getString(idx)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run the app on a different Android phone and the problem went away. So it is a device issue. The DB is not the issue. Time for a hunt.

Comment: The main difference is the phone that does it correctly is API 31 and the one the doesn't do it correctly is API 30. The Locale settings are same for both.

Comment: Discovered the reason. Did not set android:allowBackup="false". So when I uninstalled, it kept the old DB in data and it used that. My app copies its DB to data upon first run. Always the little things.

Comment: @tridiak congrats, that would not have been the easiest thing to spot.